# Web devs who have made the switch from MySQL, what postgresql features could you now not do without?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm contemplating the switch (mainly because of the more permissive license), and tend to hear a lot of Internet murmuring about how much better Postgres is than MySQL, but not many specifics. What do you do in Postgres that make you more productive, or you find elegant?

It doesn't have to be fancy, for example some of my favorite things about MySQL include

- easy primary key incrementing with AUTOINCREMENT (having to write a generator for every table seems more of a pain than it should be for such a common requirement),
- "LIMIT,OFFSET" statements (makes for easy pagination)
- ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (makes inserting/updating "many to many" tables quick and painless)

Comment: I haven't used Postgres but recently I've been working with Oracle after years of using MySQL exclusively. You're right, AUTOINCREMENT in MySQL rocks, it's a huge pain to have to create sequences for every table separately and then having to insert seq.nextval instead of simply using NULL to insert and increment the index!

Comment: Indeed you haven't used Postgres. There's a pseudo-type/syntax sugar called "SERIAL" which is as easy to use as AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PostgreSQL`'s most useful features (which `MySQL` lacks), in my opinion, are:

- `generate_series` and set returning functions in general
- ability to use correlated values in `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses
- Custom aggregates
- `DISTINCT ON` clause
- More advanced `JOIN` methods (`MERGE JOIN` and `HASH JOIN`)

You can do wonders with them.

`PostgreSQL` code also often looks more elegant (note that "looks" doesn't mean "performs"), since you can use nice casting syntax (`::`), nice `RECORD` types and these kinds of stuff.

Drawbacks are:

- You cannot use hints (I know it's intentional; I know they should be avoided; go downvote me)
- You cannot use session variables without access to server configuration files (you need to set `custom_variable_classes`)
- `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` operations are laggy.

Since both these systems are quite powerful and well-developed, they differ mainly in such fancy features (that most developers never even use).

For basic `SQL`, they're both good.

Comment: MySQL supports custom aggregate functions written in C. SQL would be better.

Comment: @Andrew: sure, but it's a pain to install them on a shared hosting or use in source distributed web apps. Nice point, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

- Transactional DDL - you can do `"start transaction; delete table foo; rollback;"` and `foo` will still be there.

Comment: What type of web development scenarios do you find yourself using this feature in?

Comment: I use it as a safety measure pretty much every time I have to alter a production database, in order to make sure I don’t do something stupid by mistake. You simply hit "commit" whenever you’re finished; if not, you can always rollback.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL, via PostGIS, offers very rich support for geospatial operators.  It's hard to imagine doing any kind of google maps integration (or similar geospatial work) with any other DB.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: MySQL supports spatial operation too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: MySQL spatial operations only work on MyISAM, forcing you to use an obsolete, slow, non-ACID engine.

Answer (score 0):

- Stored Procedures / UDFs in Perl
- Asynchronous Database Access in libpq
- Schemas and databases, not databases pretending to be schemas
- GIN and GIST

Answer (score 0):

Adding checks to fields. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "FILES" (
    ...
    md5checksum text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FILES_md5checksum_check" CHECK ((md5checksum ~* '^[a-f0-9]{32}$'::text)),
    ...
);
```

`md5checksum` field is now always validated that it's hexadecimal string and it's 32 characters long.